# Max sqlite primary key length

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need to index a table by a string that can be pretty long (from 50 to 2000 chars aprox).

Is there a limit for the length of the sqlite's primary keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of bytes in the text of an SQL statement is limited to SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH which defaults to 1000000. You can redefine this limit to be as large as the smaller of SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH and 1073741824

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if the text is also primary key, is that limit modified?

Comment: It's probably more helpful to mention that `SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH` is currently defined to "1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000)" and _that_ is "the maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite" ([source](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)). That said, it's a compile-time setting that may have been changed, e.g., by the operating system or device vendor.